# Android 3.3: Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:1

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3, sencha-touch-2.1

I have made apk for my sencha-touch project but getting this error when trying to access the phonebook contacts. Please look into the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put my sencha touch build file inside the myproject>www file of my phonegap project and also linked the cordova.js file which was already there and ran `cordova run android` and now my application is accessing phonebook. (Don't forget to add plugin for contacts `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts`)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work on iOS? If so, perhaps you have forgotten to add the [correct permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to your Manifest.xml.

Those two could be helpful:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

But only add them if you need them, because the user will get prompted with all needed permissions before he'll be able to install the application.

Another hint:

```
sencha app build testing
```

If you use this command to build your app, your app.js won't get minified an you will get the exact line of your error when building it native. This way your error is easier to debug!

[More information over here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/command_app-section-deploying-your-application)

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello Chris, In my AndroidManifest.xml file i am having:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />   But still the same issue!

Comment: I have only added cordova.js file along with build files in www folder. Do i need to include some other file too?

Comment: You don't need to add any cordova.js file to the www folder. There should only be the files which where created from your sencha build and the cordova config.xml. Cordova will create the cordova.js automatically if you run 'cordova prepare [your platform]' and 'cordova compile [your platform]' and put it into the www-folders of your platform. Therefore it uses the stuff in the 'plugin' folders in your cordova structure... If you manually add a cordova.js it will use yours.

Comment: I was putting my build file on wrong folder. I was putting it on plateform's asset's www folder rather putting it onto the top www folder of my project's hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

update cordova_plugins.xml from cordova CLI ..
I also got the same problem.I wasted half day for this but at last I updated my phonegap android project then android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.xml becomes what ever plugins I installed (At first I created phoneGap android then add's plugins using cordova CLI ... in this procedure the cordova_plugins.xml is not populated with respective "CONTACTS" plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by just uninstall and reinstall the `cordova` plugin and add `cordova-plugin-contacts`.
Then its working fine for me.